# How to sort JSON on DateTime in Powershell

Tags: json, azure, powershell, azure-container-registry

```
$registryName ="abc" 
$latestTag = "xyz"
$registryList = az acr repository list -n $registryName | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object 
{

$tagDetail = (az acr repository show-tags -n $registryName --repository $_ --detail | ConvertFrom-Json | Sort-Object lastUpdateTime -Descending)

$tagName = $tagDetail[0].name
}
```

I want to read tag whose datetime is most recent

Below is the sample json formet i get :

```
@{changeableAttributes=; createdTime=2023-05-21T19:54:21.7463638Z; digest=sha256:ec0bc571b2dbd7754ec4b7a2a95c4ef98b34b222e9711f4d547547194b833c88; lastUpdateTime=2023-05-21T19:54:21.7463638Z; name=v0.1; quarantineState=Passed; signed=False}
```

Comment: could you share the Json example as a string instead of an object?

Comment: The format of your date-time strings is such that lexical sorting is equivalent to chronological sorting, so your `Sort-Object` command _should_ work. Does it not? What happens?

Comment: `ConvertFrom-Json` writes non-enumerated output, you might have to interject `Write-Output`, eg.: `... |ConvertFrom-Json |Write-Output |Sort-Object ...`

Comment: Ah, good point, @MathiasR.Jessen. Fortunately, [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) no longer does that.

Answer (score 0):

I have created ACR registry, and pushed images with different timestamps.

[image]

Now use the below powershell script to read the repository with latest tag by datetime.

```
$registryName ="crvjy0806" 
$latestTag = "v3"
$registryList = az acr repository list -n $registryName | ConvertFrom-Json 
$t=@{}
 foreach($x in $registryList)
{

$td = (az acr repository show-tags -n $registryName --repository $x --detail | ConvertFrom-Json)
$t= ($td.lastUpdateTime| Sort-Object -Property { [datetime]::Parse($_) } -Descending)
$r=$td| Where-Object { $_.lastUpdateTime -like $t[0]}
$r.name
$r.lastUpdateTime
}
```

Output:
[image]